# Python, How to use part of function outside function

Tags: python, function, class

How can I use `today` and `returntime` in `return_fee` function?

```
import datetime

class Movie(object):
 def __init__(self,title):
    self.title = title

 def time_of_return(self):
    self.today = today
    self.returntime = returntime

    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    returntime = today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

 def return_fee(Movie):
    fee = -2
    delta = today - returntime
```

Comment: Add `self.today` and `self.returntime` to `__init__`? Then you can call `self.today` and `self.returntime` from `return_fee`. If you define them in `time_of_return` (as you did now), you can only call `return_fee` after you've called `time_of_return`.

Comment: What's the point of the `Movie` parameter of the `return_fee()` method?

Comment: The reason this code isn't working is due to variable scope, but there are some stylistic inconsistencies as well - if return_fee is intended to be a method of the Movie class (it appears to be indented like the other methods) then I would recommend changing its 'Movie' parameter to 'self' (to avoid a name clash in any case) and then I'd advise using the class instance's variables - self.fee, self.today, self.returntime  - after setting them from within the time_of_return method.  If you don't change 'Movie' to 'self' then Movie.fee would refer to a static class variable and not the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class Movie(object):
 def __init__(self,title):
    self.title = title

 def get_times(self):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now, now + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

 def time_of_return(self):
    now, returntime = self.get_times()
    return returntime

 def return_fee(self):
    fee = -2
    now, returntime = self.get_times()
    delta = now - returntime
    return <whatever based on fee and delta>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `time_of_return` and `return_fee` to be instance attributes, call `time_of_return` from `__init__` to set them and then prefix with `self`:

```
class Movie(object):
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.title = title
        self.time_of_return()

    def time_of_return(self):
        self.today = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.returntime = today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

     def return_fee(Movie):
         fee = None
         delta = self.today - self.returntime
         # ... presumably do something else
```

Alternatively (since, in particular, `today` may change over time), call the function `time_of_return` from within `return_fee` and make sure it returns something:

```
class Movie(object):
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.title = title

    def time_of_return(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        returntime = today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        return today, returntime

     def return_fee(Movie):
         fee = None
         today, returntime = self.time_of_return()
         delta = today - returntime
         # ... presumably do something else
```

It's a good idea to indent your code by 4 spaces, by the way. And `None` (or 0) would be a better default value for `fee`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Movie(object):
 def __init__(self,title,today,returntime):#<----
    self.title = title

 def time_of_return(self):
    self.today = today
    self.returntime = returntime

    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    returntime = today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

 def return_fee(Movie):
    fee = -2
    delta = today - returntime
```

That's because `__init__()` is taking arguments that using for class from outside.But, when you use your Movie class, you have to define that arguments.